# Move Data From One Retention Policy To Another In Influx DB

Tags: influxdb

We are using TICK Stack to monitor our Production. Which is in AWS autoscaling, where new server comes and goes very frequently.

We are using Grafana to visualize data from influx db by tag  host. since these new server comes and goes so there are many host which are terminated but are in db so most of host in db are terminated.

so solution to this we thought to move data after one hour to another database with a tick script.

So what is best way to do this or is there any better solution to this.

Comment: Suggest re-elaborating your use case. I'm not quite sure what it is at the moment. From my understanding so far is that your database heavily polluted by those 'temporary' instances due to `autoscaling`? So your goal is to try to remove these instances from db once they become irrelevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok little late to answer but if anyone wants they can use below tag query to get the host for last hours.

> SELECT distinct("_tagValue") FROM system WHERE "_tagKey" = 'host' AND
>   time > NOW() - 3h GROUP BY time(3h)

This will show all host for which there is data for last 3 hours

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of options here:

1. You can move the data periodically to another database using Continuous Queries: https://www.influxdata.com/blog/continuous-queries-in-influxdb-part-i/
2. Use tick script to move the data: https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/guides/continuous_queries/

The former is little tricky to manage whereas kapacitor tick scripts can be easily managed through Chronograf.

As a side note, you can also move the data to another retention policy in same database (as opposed to another db): https://community.influxdata.com/t/applying-retention-policies-to-existing-measurments/802

Comment: I have create a stream task for kapacitor but it is not updating any data to new retention policy

Comment: Can you post the core of stream task here if possible. Without that, I would only be guessing at the issue. I have successfully written a stream task to move data around.

Few things to check:
* Kapacitor is connected/subscribed to Influxdb. Can check this by just writing a dummy stream job to move data from one measurement to another in same retention policy.
* While querying the data back, make sure you are using retention policy in the query. See influxdb documentation for examples.